# mysql select не работает если задать параметры через user_variables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, user-variables

Буду краток:

**РАБОТАЕТ**

```
SELECT p.id,
    p.name,
    cat.name `category`,
    prod.name `producer`,
    p.images,
    p.price,
    p.flag_avaliable,
    p.amount,
    p.description,
    p.options
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN product_category cat ON cat.id = p.category_id
    INNER JOIN product_producer prod ON prod.id = p.producer_id
ORDER BY @asc_or_desc
    limit 5 offset 6;
```

**НЕ РАБОТАЕТ**

```
set @asc_or_desc = 'id desc ';
set @limit_number = 5;
set @offset_number = 6;
SELECT p.id,
   p.name,
   cat.name  `category`,
   prod.name `producer`,
   p.images,
   p.price,
   p.flag_avaliable,
   p.amount,
   p.description,
   p.options
FROM product p
         INNER JOIN product_category cat ON cat.id = p.category_id
         INNER JOIN product_producer prod ON prod.id = p.producer_id
ORDER BY @asc_or_desc
limit @limit_number offset @offset_number;
```

Я хочу, чтобы версия, которая "не работала" стала работать. Как мне это сделать?

Я получаю эту ошибку: `'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@limit_number offset @offset_number; END''`.

JetBrains DataGrip, MySQL 8.0.15.

**Обновление: ** Mysql не реагирует на `@asc_or_desc`. По крайней мере, сортируется как `asc`.

Comment: Порядок сортировки и лимит в принципе нельзя задавать переменными. Кроме того названия каких либо сущностей в БД таких как таблицы или колонки так же нельзя задавать в переменных нигде в запросе, а не только в order by.

Comment: Жаль, я думал, это ограничение только к именам таблиц относится... @Mike, спасибо, вы дали ответ на вопрос "Почему".

Comment: Вы кстати всесторонне проверили, что в preapred вопросительный знак в order by корректно работает ? По логике работы компилятора запросов у вас должен получаться `order by 'id asc'`, т.е. сортировка по константе, а не `order by id asc`. Потому что любые имена должны быть разрешены на стадии компиляции запроса, т.е. prepare, а не на стадии execute подготовленного запроса. По моему представлению подставить имена в order можно только `set @tatement = concat('select ... order by ', @var)`

Comment: @Mike, ответьте лучше под моим ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepared statements решили проблему.
Код:

```
set @statement =
concat('SELECT p.id,
   p.name,
   cat.name  `category`,
   prod.name `producer`,
   p.images,
   p.price,
   p.flag_avaliable,
   p.amount,
   p.description,
   p.options
FROM product p
         INNER JOIN product_category cat ON cat.id = ?
         INNER JOIN product_producer prod ON prod.id = p.producer_id
ORDER BY id ',@asc_or_desc,'
limit ? offset ?');
prepare prepared from @statement;
EXECUTE prepared USING @category_id, @limit_number, @offset_number;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepared;
```

Comment: @Mike, поправил. Сейчас точно работает, спасибо за наводку)

Comment: @Mike, этот код 100% рабочий, только что проверил, можете пользоваться